# Python, how to delete certain numbers in a list, and meanwhile delete the corresponding numbers in another list

Tags: python, arrays

For example, two lists here: `a = [1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 9, 9, 1, 1]`, `b = [1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 8, 1]`. I want to delete all the `9` in the a list, and meanwhile I want to delete all the corresponding numbers with the same positions in b list (i.e., deleting 5, 4, 2, in b). How should I achieve this? Thanks so much for the help!

code:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 9, 9, 1, 1]
b = [1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 8, 1]
c = [] #create a new list
[c.append(i) for i in a if i==9]
```

then? what should I do with b? Thanks!

Comment: Do NOT use list-comprehensions for side effects!

Comment: You can use `zip`. Is this what you're looking for: `new_a, new_b = map(list, zip(*((x, y) for x, y in zip(a,b) if x == 9)))`?

Comment: Thanks so much. this works, what I want is x != 9. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all elements from a that are equal to 9:

```
>>> [x for x in a if x != 9]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Delete all elements from b with the correct indexes:

```
>>> [b[i] for i, x in enumerate(a) if x!=9]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 8, 1]
```